# Buttons are showing in preview but not on phone

Tags: java, android, button, widget

I'm was practicing building buttons (all testing was fine), so I'm moving on to widgets. Now when I hit run in Android Studio, it shows my build was successful, the buttons show on my preview screen, but the app on my phone is completely blank.

Here is my .java

```
package com.android.woo.datetimepickerdialog;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import com.example.android.woo.R;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
    EditText txtDate, txtTime;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnDatePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btnTimePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_date);
        txtTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_time);

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnDatePicker) {

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == btnTimePicker) {

            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SELECT DATE"
        android:id="@+id/btn_date"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/in_date" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/in_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SELECT TIME"
        android:id="@+id/btn_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_date"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_date" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Adding my Manifest for review:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.woo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Woo"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it the only activity you have in your application?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your manifest but I would guess that you are either starting on a different activity, or have another variation of your activity_main.xml (landscape? x-large?)

Comment: for Button try giving android:background it will visible :)

Comment: Yes, this is the only activity. I added my manifest for review as well.

Comment: android:background? I'm confused! @jaffar

Comment: @KrystalStone : paste this as Button attribute          android:background="@android:color/black"  run and check

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That made the change in my preview of Android Studio, but still nothing is showing on my Samsung Galaxy S7. @jaffar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import com.example.android.woo.datetimepickerdialog.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your manifest.xml to make sure your MainActivity is the launcher activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If this is good, check if you have any other variation of your activity_main.xml:
[image]

For example, if your test device is a tablet and your xlarge layout is empty, you won't see anything.

Comment: My manifest matches up to what you gave, and I'm not seeing anything variations listed.

Comment: What is your test device and which version of Android does it run?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S7. Running Android 7.0. @Distwo

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong. Hard to say more without seeing the entire project.